# Jquery .validate require_from_group

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Whenever i use `require_from_group` it disables all other validations. Any ideas why?

Also is there a way to group "Telefon" and "Mobitel" and apply `require_from_group` to it?

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fncMain").validate(
    {
    /*groups:{Call:"Telefon Mobitel"},*/
    rules:{
        Davcna:{required:true,exactlength:5, digits:true},
        Idzav:{required:true,exactlength:5, digits:true},
        Maticna:{required:true,exactlength:5, digits:true},
        Telefon:{require_from_group: [1,".callme"]},
        Mobitel:{require_from_group: [1,".callme"]}
    }, 
    messages:{

    }}
    );
  });
```

All other fields not included here use simple "required" class. If i remove `require_from_group` rules applied to "Telefon" and "Mobitel" all other field validations work fine.

Thanks for help.

**EDIT** html : http://cl.ly/29391q0Q3G231T2I380m  (too long to post it here)

Comment: Can you share the html for this form, at least as it relates to these rules?  i.e. what things have the class `callme`, etc

Comment: @Ryley i posted my HTML (form part). Check the edit of my post. :)

Comment: I think you've found a bug...

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/412) for details on the potential bug.  If that ends up being the resolution, post it as an answer here and ping me for upvotes :)

Comment: Hehe i actually posted this bug report :) Thanks for simplifying it ;)

Comment: running into the same issue, no resolution yet?  any workarounds?

Answer (score 5):

@Tats_innit posted a custom `require_from_group` here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13127475

Turns out, this also fixes a logged github bug that was released with version 1.10.0 of `require_from_group` in `additional-method-1.10.js` for `jquery.validation`.

**github issue:
[require_from_group disables other rules](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/412)**

smileyanp@github quoted this post in his solution where he reused @Tats_innit's function and created a [test](http://jsfiddle.net/hfLwB/4/) that showed it works correctly **and doesn't disable** validation on other rules defined prior to the `require_from_group`.

This post is here as a time saver as this burned 3 hrs of googling for such a small detail..

**FIX:**

Just update `additional-method-1.10.js` or execute this code after `additional-method-1.10.js` has loaded (to overwrite the function).

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function(value, element, options) {
  var numberRequired = options[0];
  var selector = options[1];
  var fields = $(selector, element.form);
  var filled_fields = fields.filter(function() {
    // it's more clear to compare with empty string
    return $(this).val() != ""; 
  });
  var empty_fields = fields.not(filled_fields);
  // we will mark only first empty field as invalid
  if (filled_fields.length < numberRequired && empty_fields[0] == element) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
// {0} below is the 0th item in the options field
}, jQuery.format("Please fill out at least {0} of these fields."));
```

Comment: In comparing the behavior of the 1.11.1 version of this function with the version in this answer I've noticed that this version doesn't appear to do the greedy revalidation like the shipping version does.  This version does revalidate on form submit, but the shipping one clears the validation messages as soon as the minimum number of fields have values in them (onkeyup).  Just an FYI in case anyone requires the greedy revalidation for their use case.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**:  It actually looks like this fix has been incorporated into version 1.12.0 and you can find the CDN pointers for it here:  [**http://jqueryvalidation.org/**](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

And for reference:

```
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.min.js
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.min.js
```

I found this code below before I found the solution above, so my advice is to use the CDN links referenced above instead of pasting the code below into your JS file.

There is a [**better fix out on GitHub now**](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/412) (scroll to the very bottom), which I've copied here.  ***This is not my work*** and the GitHub user sfreytag who wrote it, does not appear to be an SO contributor, I just wanted to get it into SO so other people who find this don't have to dig through threads on GitHub:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function(value, element, options) {
    var validator = this;
    var selector = options[1];
    var validOrNot = $(selector, element.form).filter(function() {
        return validator.elementValue(this);
    }).length >= options[0];

    if(!$(element).data('being_validated')) {
        var fields = $(selector, element.form);
        fields.data('being_validated', true);
        fields.valid();
        $(element.form).valid();
        fields.data('being_validated', false);
    }
    return validOrNot;
}, jQuery.format("Please fill at least {0} of these fields."));
```

I have done limited testing with this thus far, but it appears to be working as you'd expect, all validations occur (instead of blowing through any non "require_from_group" validations as before), so I'm happy with it so far.  I just added it after the the validator declaration in the top of my JS code:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    debug: true,
    success: "valid"
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function(value, element, options) {
    var validator = this;
    var selector = options[1];
   //continuation of code...
```

Comment: This is the version that worked for me.  It doesn't break other rules, and revalidates the group fields on keyup.