# JQuery validate multiple groups not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the below jQuery to validate multiple groups, but after updating my code to the method in this link: [Jquery .validate require_from_group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469913/jquery-validate-require-from-group) , I'm having an issue where everything is validated except the second group, which worked fine before.

```
  $("#contact-form").validate({
    groups: {
      links: "link_fb link_yt link_db",
      checkboxes: "tracking mixing mastering reamping editing other"
    },
    rules: {
      'link_fb': {
        require_from_group: [1, ".link_group"]
      },
      'link_yt': {
        require_from_group: [1, ".link_group"]
      },
      'link_db': {
        require_from_group: [1, ".link_group"]
      },
      'tracking': {
        require_from_group: [1, ".checkbox_group"]
      },
      'mixing': {
        require_from_group: [1, ".checkbox_group"]
      },
      'mastering': {
        require_from_group: [1, ".checkbox_group"]
      },
      'reamping': {
        require_from_group: [1, ".checkbox_group"]
      },
      'editing': {
        require_from_group: [1, ".checkbox_group"]
      },
      'other': {
        require_from_group: [1, ".checkbox_group"]
      }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) { 
      console.log(element[0])
      if(element[0].value === "tracking")
      {
        error.insertBefore(element);
      }
      else {
        error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    }
  });
```

Here is the markup for the form:

```
<!--Request Quote modal-->
<div id="request-quote" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="760">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3>Request a quote</h3>
  </div>
  <form method="POST" action="contact-form-submission.php" class="form-horizontal" id="contact-form">
  <div class="modal-body contact-body"> 
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span12">
        <h4>*All information is required unless otherwise specified</h4>
        <p><label>Full Name</label>
        <input name="name" type="text" class="span12" required></p>
        <p><label>Band Name</label>
        <input name="band_name" type="text" class="span12" required></p>
        <p><label>Email</label>
        <input name="email" type="email" class="span12" required></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <h5 class="span12">Links to your band (at least one is required)</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span12">
        <p><label>Facebook</label>
        <input name="link_fb" type="text" class="span12 link_group"></p>
        <p><label>YouTube</label>
        <input name="link_yt" type="text" class="span12 link_group"></p>
        <p><label>Dropbox (Send me some of your band's prior material)</label>
        <input name="link_db" type="text" class="span12 link_group"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <h5 class="span12">What are you looking for?</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span4">
        <p><label>Select all that apply:</label></p>
        <p class="form-boxes"><label class="hand">
        <input name="tracking" type="checkbox" value="tracking" class="checkbox_group"> Tracking
        </label>
        <label class="hand">
        <input name="mixing" type="checkbox" value="mixing" class="checkbox_group"> Mixing
        </label>
        <label class="hand">
        <input name="mastering" type="checkbox" value="mastering" class="checkbox_group"> Mastering
        </label>
        <label class="hand">
        <input name="reamping" type="checkbox" value="reamping" class="checkbox_group"> Reamping
        </label>
        <label class="hand">
        <input name="editing" type="checkbox" value="editing" class="checkbox_group"> Editing
        </label>
        <label class="hand">
        <input name="other" type="checkbox" value="other" class="checkbox_group"> Other
        </label></p>
      </div>
      <div class="span8">
        <p><label>Number of Songs</label>
        <input name="songs" type="text" class="span12" required></p>
        <p><label>Explain your project/needs (and if you selected "other", please clarify)</label>
        <textarea name="comments" class="span12" required></textarea></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-inverse">Close</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
<!--/Request Quote modal-->
```

Anyone have any ideas what's up?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here's the most up-to-date require_from_group method (not in the main github branch), you'll see my issue using this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function(value, element, options) {
  var numberRequired = options[0];
  var selector = options[1];
  var fields = $(selector, element.form);
  var filled_fields = fields.filter(function() {
    // it's more clear to compare with empty string
    return $(this).val() != ""; 
  });
  var empty_fields = fields.not(filled_fields);
  // we will mark only first empty field as invalid
  if (filled_fields.length < numberRequired && empty_fields[0] == element) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
// {0} below is the 0th item in the options field
}, jQuery.format("Please fill out at least {0} of these fields."));
```

**EDIT2:**

Here is a jsfiddle showing the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/THinesley/mnEVj/1/

Comment: I was having some trouble getting your code to run in a jsFiddle.  However, after removing the `console.log` from the `errorPlacement` callback, I got the fiddle working.  However, I do not see the problem you describe:  http://jsfiddle.net/wwBQq/

Comment: There were a couple known issues with the `require_from_group` method.  Both fixed in the latest version of the plugin, AFAIK.

Comment: @Sparky if you look at your jsfiddle, the first three fields are not being marked as required. I can submit without those being required. Look at my edit in the post above to see which require_from_group method you need to make it work, but then you'll see my issue.

Comment: @Sparky to clarify, the first three fields are set to required and SHOULD be validated, along with both groups and the other two required fields at the bottom. That's why neither my code nor yours works 100%.