# jQuery Validation plugin - validate group of input fields and at least one group is required

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate my form with *jQuery Validate Plugin*.
My form require at least one pair of this input (ex: `mobilePhone`/`mobilePhone_p` or/and `personalPhone`/`personalPhone_p` or/and `workPhone`/`workPhone_p`)
but I don't know how to link one text field (phone number) with his associated radio button (preferred yes/no) for validating my form and validate there is at least one pair.
If one or multiple pair is set, my form also require at least one checked radio button.

HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="phoneForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="mobilePhone">Mobile</label></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="mp_phone" name="mobilePhone" id="mobilePhone" value="" />
            </td>
            <td><label for="mobilePhone_p">Preferred phone number</label> <input type="radio" name="num_p" id="mobilePhone_p" value="mobilePhone_p" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="personalPhone">Personal</label></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="mp_phone" name="personalPhone" id="personalPhone" value="" />
            </td>
            <td><label for="personalPhone_p">Preferred phone number</label> <input type="radio" name="num_p" id="personalPhone_p" value="personalPhone_p" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="workPhone">Work</label></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="mp_phone" name="workPhone" id="workPhone" value="" />
            </td>
            <td><label for="workPhone_p">Preferred phone number</label> <input type="radio" name="num_p" id="workPhone_p" value="workPhone_p" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" id="validateFormButton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

jQuery Validate :

```
$("#phoneForm").validate({
    rules: {
        mobilePhone: {
            phone: true,
            require_from_group: [1,".mp_phone"]
        },
        personalPhone: {
            phone: true,
            require_from_group: [1,".mp_phone"]
        },
        workPhone: {
            phone: true,
            require_from_group: [1,".mp_phone"]
        },
        num_p: {
            required: true
        }
    }   
});
```

(`phone` is a custom method to validate phone number and `require_from_group` is defined in http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js)

It's works when fields require at least one text field but radio button groups is not validated when `require_from_group` is set on other fields...

How can I validate my form using jQuery Validation plugin ?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469913/jquery-validate-require-from-group

Comment: @MichaelB., that question has nothing to do with what he's asking.  The bug described there has since been fixed in the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by customizing `require_from_group` method (based on [Jquery .validate require_from_group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469913/jquery-validate-require-from-group)) :

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("require_from_group_with_radio", function(value, element, options) {
    var numberRequired = options[0];
    var selector = options[1];
    var fields = jQuery(selector, element.form);
    var filled_fields = fields.filter(function() {
        // check if not empty and radio is checked
        return jQuery(this).val() !== "" && jQuery(this).closest("tr").find("input:radio").is(":checked"); 
    });
    var empty_fields = fields.not(filled_fields);
    // we will mark only first empty field as invalid
    if (filled_fields.length < numberRequired && empty_fields[0] == element) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}, jQuery.format("Please fill out at least {0} of these fields and one of this associated option."));
```

Validate:

```
$("#phoneForm").validate({
    rules: {
        mobilePhone: {
            phone: true,
            require_from_group: [1,".mp_phone"],
            require_from_group_with_radio: [1,".mp_phone"]
        },
        personalPhone: {
            phone: true,
            require_from_group: [1,".mp_phone"],
            require_from_group_with_radio: [1,".mp_phone"]
        },
        workPhone: {
            phone: true,
            require_from_group: [1,".mp_phone"],
            require_from_group_with_radio: [1,".mp_phone"]
        }
    }   
});
```

Just adding `jQuery(this).closest("tr").find("input:radio").is(":checked")` in filter condition.

We have just parameterize the radio selector to be generic.